# Prebuilt intents and trainingphrases agents for Google Assistant Action in german or spanish

Tags: dialogflow-es, multilingual, voice, google-assistant-sdk

I'm working on a music player for the *Google Assistant Action*. Are there pre-built **agents** for **Intents** and **Trainingsphases** available for languages other than English?

It seems possible to upload a JSON file with intents.

Are there resource available for spanish and/or german intents?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take Intents from pre-built intents, from each intent fetch the training phrase and translate them into desired language then compile intent of your own.
This process requires interacting with Dialogflow using rest API's.
[This reference page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents) will help you understand different required API's.

Also, as you said, it is possible to upload json of intents so maybe convert the translated intents into json file and upload them manually.